# A piece of data in an excel column is not recognized when using the not equal to "<>" in vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter out all values but one specific value in an excel column.

Code:

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$7").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>222418"`

WorkSheet Picture:

[image]

This code works fine when the `criteria1` parameter is set to "222418", but it fails when changing `criteria1` to "<>222418".

What is wrong and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: how exactly does it fail?

Comment: It treats the criteria as if it is blank, I mean, as if it is like this: criteria1:=" " , because there is not blank cells in column C, it does nothing.

Comment: Is the Criteria1 parameter hardcoded like you show or is it passed by a variable? if so, please show how you do it.

Comment: in my original code it is passed by a varialble this way: Criteria1:="<>" & AccountNumber

Comment: Can you verify that AccountNumber is indeed "222418"? put a `debug.print AccountNumber` right bevore the AutoFilter command or halt the code and hover with the mouse cursor over the variable or look it up in the Local Window.

Comment: I did all that steps you describe but the same happens. I guess the problem is in the data itself, the format of the data is neither text nor number, it is something else that I can't identify. the TypeName property returns text but AutoFilter has another openion

Comment: I had this happening to me when exporting a list from some database tool to excel. I think i solved it by looping through the list in excel and running a `.Value = .Value` on each cell.